# lazy load (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazyloading

Добрый день. Использую spring + hibernate.

Сконфигурировал все:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "ua" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:db.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    PGPoolingDataSource dataSource = new PGPoolingDataSource();
    dataSource.setServerName(env.getProperty("db.server.name"));
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(env.getProperty("db.name"));
    dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    dataSource.setMaxConnections(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("db.connections")));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ua.persistence.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
}
```

написал дао:

```
@Repository("userDAO")
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public User getById(Long id) {
    return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
}
}
```

и пытаюсь из main протестить.

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

UserDAO dao = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDAO");

    User user = dao.getById(61L);
    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println(user.getRoles());
}
```

Строка System.out.println(user); выводит юзера норамльно, но если потом обратится к его ролям, вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ua.persistence.model.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Мой юзер pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"user\"")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "second_name")
private String secondName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "registration_date")
private Timestamp registrationDate;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_role",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_user")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_role")})
private List<Role> roles;
//getters and setters
}
```

Я так понимаю, при первом обращении к базе за юзером. хибернейт его спокойно достает, но если потом обратится к его ролям, которые по идее должны лениво подгружаться, сессия уже закрыта и вылетает ексепшн.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

**ps: lazy load необходим, и убирать его в моём случае нельзя.**

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь это из за транзакции. У вас getById работает в ней. После того как транзакция закрывается закрывается и сессия. Думаю для данного метода она ни к чему. В классе дао поставьте для каждого метода оптиционально аннотацию transactional, а с самого класса ее уберите.

Если это невозможно сделать, то воспользуйтесь методом Hibernate.initialize или в транзакции обратитесь к полям, которые загружаются лениво.

Comment: да, но если у меня например будет метод, который таки нуждается в транзакции. Как тогда быть?

Comment: Хорошо, дополнил ответ для вашего случая

Comment: спасибо за ответ. У меня есть ещё один вопрос. Почему если поменять в юзер pojo FetchType.lazy на eager ситуация не меняется, хотя по идее всё должно загружаться сразу..

Comment: Довольно странная ситуация, проверьте правильность того, что у вас написано в JoinTable и название колонок в таблицах. Скорее всего у вас просто некорректно указан релейшн.

Comment: хм, странно..ничего не поменял, но теперь всё работает) Спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

Сразу загрузите `User` с ролями из БД в вашем `UserDAOImpl`, код:

```
@Override
public User getById(Long id) {
    return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("select distinct u from User u left join fetch u.roles where u.id = :id ")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: юзера загружать с ролями, а роли с юзерами?) Слишком много грузить получится за раз

Comment: В моем случае делается один запрос в БД, который возвращает количество строк равное количеству ролей (декартово произведение: 1 умноженное на roles.size), и больше не делает запросов. В результате получаете 1 объект юзера и несколько объектов ролей (например 3 роли), т.е. всего 4 объекта. У юзера есть ссылка на коллекцию ролей (3 роли), и у каждой роли есть ссылка на полученного юзера. Если Вы у роли получите юзера, запроса в БД уже не будет.

Comment: Допустим у юзера есть 1 роль. Если обратится к этой  роли, то у нее есть список всех юзеров, у которых есть эта роль. Тоесть придется опять в базу за остальными юзерами лесть.

Comment: Да, правильно, нужно будет лезть, только незачем. Создайте 2 метода: 1 - получение пользователя с ролями, 2 - получение роли(по ее названию или ИД) с пользователями. Какую задачу хотите решить получая юзера, у юзера роли, у роли юзеров... ?